# How to find the length of a path between two nodes in a tree?

Tags: java, tree

I want to calculate the path between two arbitrary nodes in a tree (implemented in Java).
Are there in literature any solutions?

Comment: It depends on your data structure, how you are representing the tree in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
               10(root)
               /\
              8  11
             / \   \
            7   9   15
```

distance(7, 9) = 2

We can calculate the distance(root, 7) = 2, and calculate distance(root, 9) = 2, LCA(7, 9) = 8. LCA stands for "Lowest Common Ancestor" Therefore, `distance(7, 9) = distance(root, 7) + distance(root, 9) - 2*distance(root, LCA) = 2 + 2 - 2*1 = 2`

Now you can see the method; the real question for you is how to calculate distance(root, anyNode). This is a common question, I assume you shall be able to find how to find the distance to any desired node soon.

Comment: What if the input is dist(11,15)? My tree is arbitrary and not binary, so the results should  be 1. But dist(root,11)=1 + dist(root,15)=2 -2*dist(root,lca)=0...so 3. This is wrong of course. How to deal with this problem? Or maybe the lca in this case is 11 itself?

Comment: Yes! The case you mentioned would be: dist(root,11) + dist(root, 15) - 2*LCA(root, LCA) = 1 + 2 - 2*1 = 1. The LCA is 11 itself. When you try to find its "Lowest Common Ancestor", always start from the root. Thus, the path of node11 is 10 - 11, and for node15 is 10 - 11- 15, so LCA is 11.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the distance between two nodes in a tree by using the common ancestor.

Should be something like this :

```
Dist(n1, n2) = Dist(root, n1) + Dist(root, n2) - 2*Dist(root, lca)
```

Comment: And a way to find the lowest common ancestor is to compare the paths from the root to each of n1 and n2. The last node on the shared path is the LCA.